# Unit testing UIImage from a URL

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uiimage

I'm trying to test a function that creates an image from a url. My unit test looks like this:

```
func testImageFromURL() {

    //when testing callbacks use a testExpectation
    let testExpectation = expectation(description: "Format function timed out")

    //1.Given
    let dictPhotoData = ["isfriend":false, "farm": 1, "id":"40946679254", "server":"875", "secret":"c6e491e979", "owner":"138560875@N08", "title":"Is it spring yet? Eastern garter snake (Thamnophis sirtalis)", "ispublic":true, "isfamily":false] as [String : Any]

    //2.When
    let thisPhotoObj = FF_PhotoObject(dictPhotoData)
    if let thisPhotoURL = thisPhotoObj?.photoUrl as? URL {

        myAPIManager.getImageFromData(thisPhotoURL, completion: { (_ thisImage:UIImage) in

            //3. Then
            //-->Not sure what to test for here.
            testExpectation.fulfill()

        })
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 7) { error in
        if let error = error {
            XCTFail("waitForExpectationsWithTimeout errored: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure what to test for the UIImage.

Comment: It seems to me that you are testing the wrong thing. What does `myAPIManager` do? What you want to test is the stuff inside _that_. Basically you want to mock this object, probably using dependency injection.

Comment: I'm with @matt. Also, as a general rule, you never want to put real-deal network calls in unit tests.

Comment: I'm with @jakehawken :). We already _know_ what _Apple's_ code does. So if you are testing something that depends on Apple's code, you're doing it wrong. You want to test just _your_ code. BTW there is a very good WWDC 2017 video on this very topic.